# Excel VBA PDF Converted Text Extraction

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with some code that was written for me, and I am having trouble with the Department value. I do not want it to only put out one word which is what it is doing now, and I do not know where to place it so that it doesn't remove all of the text except for just one word. This is the code:

(One of the lines will not space over to change it into a code view and I'm not sure how to fix that)

```
'===============================================================
Private Enum i_
    ž__NONE = 0
  ID
  Last
  First
  Middle
  Rank
  Department
    ž__
    ž__FIRST = ž__NONE + 1
    ž__LAST = ž__ - 1
End Enum

Public Sub EditedVersion_ExtractFieldValues()



  Const l_Table_1     As String = "Table 1"
  Const l_FieldValues As String = "FieldValues"
  Const l_last_first_middle As String = "last first middle"
  Const s_FieldNames        As String = "id " & l_last_first_middle & " rank" & " department"
  Const n_OutputRowsPerRecord As Long = 7

  Dim ƒ As Excel.WorksheetFunction: Set ƒ = Excel.WorksheetFunction
  Dim ¡ As Long
  Dim dictFields As Object


 Set dictFields = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 dictFields.CompareMode = vbTextCompare


  With Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    .Add(After:=.Item(.count)).name = l_FieldValues
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      If .Item(.count).name <> l_FieldValues Then
        .Item(.count).Delete
        .Item(l_FieldValues).UsedRange.Clear
      End If
      .Item(l_FieldValues).Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .Item(l_Table_1).Activate
  End With

  Dim astrFieldNames() As String
  astrFieldNames = Split(" " & s_FieldNames, " ") ' Force index zero to a blank -> treat as base 1


  With dictFields
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    For ¡ = i_.ž__FIRST To i_.ž__LAST
      dictFields.Add astrFieldNames(¡), ""
    Next ¡
  End With
  Dim lngLastUsedRow As Long
  lngLastUsedRow _
  = Cells _
 .find _
      ( _
        What:="*" _
      , After:=Cells(1) _
      , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
      , Lookat:=xlPart _
      , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
      , SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
      ) _
     .Row

  With Range(Rows(1), Rows(lngLastUsedRow))

    Dim arngFoundCells(i_.ž__FIRST To i_.ž__LAST) As Range
    For ¡ = i_.ž__FIRST To i_.ž__LAST
      Set arngFoundCells(¡) = .find(What:=astrFieldNames(¡),  After:=Cells(1))
    Next ¡
    Dim lngFirstFoundRow As Long
    lngFirstFoundRow _
    = ƒ.Min _
        ( _
          arngFoundCells(i_.Last).Row _
        , arngFoundCells(i_.First).Row _
        , arngFoundCells(i_.Middle).Row _
        )
    Dim lngOuputSheetNextRow As Long
    lngOuputSheetNextRow = 1

    Dim varFoundCell As Variant
    Dim lngNextFoundRow As Long
    Dim rngNextFindStart As Range
    Dim astrSplitValues() As String
    Dim strFoundValue As String
    Dim lngFieldCount As Long
    Do
      For ¡ = i_.ž__FIRST To i_.ž__LAST
        'Debug.Print arngFoundCells(¡).Address; " ";
        dictFields.Item(astrFieldNames(¡)) = ""
      Next ¡
      Debug.Print
      Select Case True
        Case arngFoundCells(i_.First).Row = arngFoundCells(i_.Middle).Row:
      ' Edge case: missing rank (found rank is for next employee) -> copy first to rank (simplifies following code)
          'If varFoundCels(
          If arngFoundCells(i_.Rank).Row <> arngFoundCells(i_.First).Row Then
            Set arngFoundCells(i_.Rank) = arngFoundCells(i_.First)
          End If

          For Each varFoundCell In arngFoundCells
            If Not varFoundCell Like astrFieldNames(i_.Department) Then
            strFoundValue = ƒ.Trim(Replace(Replace(varFoundCell.Value2, vbLf, " "), ":", "")) & " "
            If strFoundValue Like "[']*" Then strFoundValue =     Mid$(strFoundValue, 2)
            ' ID field: only retain the first word of value
            End If
            If LCase$(strFoundValue) Like astrFieldNames(i_.ID) & "*" Then
              strFoundValue = Left$(strFoundValue, InStr(InStr(strFoundValue, " ") + 1, strFoundValue, " "))
            End If
            ' Department field: only retain the first word of value'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''THIS IS THE DEPARTMENT FIELD
            If (varFoundCell) Like astrFieldNames(i_.Department) & " " Then
              strFoundValue = Trim(varFoundCell.Value)
            End If
            ' Edge case: no last name value in merged cell -> assume value is in first cell of following row
            Debug.Print LCase$(strFoundValue)
            If LCase$(strFoundValue) Like astrFieldNames(i_.Last) & " " Then
              strFoundValue = ƒ.Trim(strFoundValue & Rows(varFoundCell.Row + 1).Cells(1).Value2) & " "
            End If
            ' Edge case: Field names only in row -> assume field values are on the following row
            If LCase$(strFoundValue) Like l_last_first_middle & "*" _
            And Len(strFoundValue) - Len(Replace(strFoundValue, " ", "")) < 5 _
            Then
              strFoundValue = ƒ.Trim(strFoundValue & Rows(varFoundCell.Row + 1).Cells(1).Value2) & " "
            End If
            astrSplitValues = Split(" " & strFoundValue, " ") ' Force index zero to a blank -> treat as base 1
            ' Array contains one/some/all field names first and then the values (with a possible extra blank value)
            lngFieldCount = Int(UBound(astrSplitValues) / 2)
            For ¡ = 1 To lngFieldCount
              dictFields.Item(astrSplitValues(¡)) = astrSplitValues(¡ + lngFieldCount)
            Next ¡


          Next varFoundCell


           'Only allow the id to be on the previous row
          If arngFoundCells(i_.ID).Row <> arngFoundCells(i_.First).Row - 1 Then
            dictFields.Item(astrFieldNames(i_.ID)) = 0
          End If
        Case Else
          Debug.Print "  SKIPPED: ";
          For ¡ = i_.ž__FIRST To i_.ž__LAST
            'Debug.Print arngFoundCells(¡).Address; " ";
          Next ¡
          Debug.Print
          For ¡ = i_.ž__FIRST To i_.ž__LAST
            Debug.Print "    "; ƒ.Trim(arngFoundCells(¡).Value2)
          Next ¡
          Debug.Print
      End Select
Sheets(l_FieldValues).Columns(1).Cells(lngOuputSheetNextRow).Resize(n_OutputRowPerRecord - 1).Value = ƒ.Transpose(dictFields.Items)
      lngOuputSheetNextRow = lngOuputSheetNextRow + n_OutputRowsPerRecord
      Set rngNextFindStart = Rows(arngFoundCells(i_.First).Row + 2).Cells(1)
      For ¡ = i_.ž__FIRST To i_.ž__LAST
        Set arngFoundCells(¡) = .find(What:=astrFieldNames(¡),         
After:=rngNextFindStart)
      Next ¡
      lngNextFoundRow _
  = ƒ.Min _
      ( _
        arngFoundCells(i_.Last).Row _
      , arngFoundCells(i_.First).Row _
      , arngFoundCells(i_.Middle).Row _
      )
    Loop While lngNextFoundRow <> lngFirstFoundRow
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please clean up your code. There is way too much for us to effectively look at. Reduce your code to a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @luuklag, I would have made it shorter, but I'm not sure how to do that with this code because I do not know which part of the code is affecting how the department is output. The way this is written is far beyond my knowledge of VBA

Comment: @luuklag If i can help in any other way please let me know. I've been going through and copying small pieces of the code and testing them to see what they do so I can figure out which part I need to alter